# How to bring dropdown and textbox in one line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing a search bar in which it has Dropdown for Location and Textbox for Search. Before applying bootstrap it was in one line, but after applying bootstrap it came one below another and no matter what values, display or position I change, it won't come in one line. How should I fix this?

Picture and code attached below for reference.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s3Ka.jpg)

```css
.homewall
{
    height: 480px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo
{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    background: white;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.heading
{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25%;  
}

.search
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}

.locdd
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 245px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 21px;
}

.restInput
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 477px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 21px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    .restInput 
    {
      height: 40px;
      width: 245px;
      color: gray;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;  
      opacity: 0.7;
      float: left;
    }

    .homewall
    {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .logo 
    {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 80px;
      color: red;
      background: white;
      width: 115px;
      height: 123px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      margin-left: 38%;
      margin-right: 40%;
    }

    .locdd 
    {
      position: relative;
      top: -238px;
      margin-left: 23.5%;
      margin-right: 20%;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<img class="homewall" src="#" height="50%" width="100%"/>
<div class="logo">
Logo   
</div>
<div class="heading">
Find the best Restaurants, Cafes and Bars
</div>  
<div class="search">
<select class="locdd">
<option>Select Location</option>
<option value="Mum">Mumbai</option>
<option value="Del">Delhi</option>
<option value="Bglr">Bangalore</option>
</select>
<div style="position: relative;">   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="position: absolute; font-size: 2rem; top: 40px; left: 35px"></span>
<input class="restInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Restaurant or Food" style="padding-left: 50px;"/>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the tag for only that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to start from the same position from the left, you need to get rid of the center alignment that you have placed on `.search` . Also avoid using exact position values as it might break in different screen size. Remove alignment of the container, and then both of them will have the same horizontal starting point if that is what you needed.

```css
.homewall
{
    height: 480px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo
{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    background: white;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.heading
{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25%;  
}

.search
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
}

.locdd
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 245px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 21px;
}

.restInput
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 477px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 21px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    .restInput 
    {
      height: 40px;
      width: 245px;
      color: gray;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;  
      opacity: 0.7;
      float: left;
    }

    .homewall
    {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .logo 
    {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 80px;
      color: red;
      background: white;
      width: 115px;
      height: 123px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      margin-left: 38%;
      margin-right: 40%;
    }

    .locdd 
    {
      position: relative;
      top: -238px;
      margin-left: 23.5%;
      margin-right: 20%;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<img class="homewall" src="#" height="50%" width="100%"/>
<div class="logo">
Logo   
</div>
<div class="heading">
Find the best Restaurants, Cafes and Bars
</div>  
<div class="search">
<select class="locdd">
<option>Select Location</option>
<option value="Mum">Mumbai</option>
<option value="Del">Delhi</option>
<option value="Bglr">Bangalore</option>
</select>
<div >   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="position: absolute; font-size: 2rem; top: 40px; left: 35px"></span>
<input class="restInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Restaurant or Food" />
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap select button and search box in a div add `display: flex` to wrapper.

```css
.homewall {
    height: 480px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-row {
    position: relative; /* we have to add position: relative to the parent of banner-text*/
}

/* I've added a new class' */

.banner-text { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    background: white;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 110px;
    display: flex; /* to center logo */
    align-items: center; /* to vetically center logo */
    justify-content: center; /* to horizontally center logo */
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center; 
}

/* to set dropdown and searchbox to one line */

.search {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

.locdd {
    height: 60px;
    width: 245px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.restInput {
    height: 60px;
    width: 477px;
    color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    .restInput {
        height: 50px;
        width: 245px;
        color: gray;
        border: none;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .homewall {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .logo {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 80px;
        color: red;
        background: white;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .locdd {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="row banner-row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <img class="homewall" src="#" height="50%" width="100%"/>
                <div class="banner-text">
                    <div class="logo">
                        Logo   
                    </div>
                    <div class="heading">
                        Find the best Restaurants, Cafes and Bars
                    </div>  
                    <div class="search">
                        <select class="locdd ">
                            <option>Select Location</option>
                            <option value="Mum">Mumbai</option>
                            <option value="Del">Delhi</option>
                            <option value="Bglr">Bangalore</option>
                        </select>
                        <div style="position: relative; border-left: 1px solid #ccc;">   
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="position: absolute; font-size: 2rem; top: 50%; left: 15px; transform: translateY(-50%);"></span>
                            <input class="restInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Restaurant or Food" style="padding-left: 50px;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```